# Is there something equivalent to the command-line parameters for the AjaxMinTask?

Tags: microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I would like to use the -res switch for the ajaxmintask in the proj file.  However, I can't find any documentation on how this can be done.  I know how to do it via command line but if there is a way to add switches via the proj file that would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

There task has a catch-all "Switches" property. It's a string property you can set *almost* all of the command-line switches for the task. The -res switch is one of the supported switches.